# DNN API Url's 404'ing

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I upgraded a site from 7.2 to 7.3.1 all seemed ok for a while, but then someone tried editing the site and we now see that a lot of the API url's are 404'ing so we cannot change to edit mode, use the file manager, etc...

A few sample url's that are broken:

/DesktopModules/internalservices/API/controlbar/ToggleUserMode
/DesktopModules/internalservices/API/controlbar/RecycleApplicationPool

What could cause this?  All was working well with 7.2  I am grateful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the System.Net.Http dll was wrong, I pulled a copy from a working 7.3.1 install and am back to normal.

Comment: It sounds a lot like my experience after I upgraded to a newer WebAPI:  http://www.dnnsoftware.com/answers/upgraded-to-web-api2-and-services-returning-4040

Comment: when this has happened to me more recently, I simply grab the dll's from an install package of dnn and overwrite the ones in the problem site, normally fixes it.

Comment: The problem is that the DLLs from DNN are very old - I need the latest versions of the ASP.NET WebAPI to use Breeze and the latest version of EF for my mobile apps which I am writing that connect to my site. So I intentionally update the DNN dlls, which breaks it...  apparently the core team will be updating to newer components in the next major release

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else has this problem, I found I had a missing WebFormsMvp.dll.

I found this by using the Fusion Log Viewer (log bind failures to disk) and analysing each error in the log.